# jquery : detecting scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, footer

I want to get an alert when, while scrolling, my footer comes to view.

```
$(window).on("mousewheel", function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#footer').position().top){    
        alert("footer visible");
    }  
    else{
        alert("footer invisible");  
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JRUnr/10/

All conditions with height seem right, but not during scrolling.

Comment: The only problem was that you had a syntax error. Corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/JRUnr/11/

Comment: And yes, you need to use `offset()` to get the position w.r.t. document top - as in the fiddle above.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/JRUnr/15/)**

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('.footer').offset().top) {
        alert("footer visible");
    } else {
        alert("footer invisible");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Thanks - this was a big help!

Answer (score 4):

There is a jquery plugin for this task named jQuery Waypoints 
(http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

```
$('#footer').waypoint(function(direction) {
    alert('Top of thing hit top of viewport.');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a working fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/JRUnr/14/

it is hacked together but it works

```
        flag=true;


$(window).scroll(function() {
    st=$(window).scrollTop();
    $('#topscroll').html(st)


    if(st>1450){
        if(flag)
        alert('test');flag=false;
    }

});
```

Comment: This is a great example, works on every pixel travelled.