# Binding a function to a horizontal or vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to bind different behavior to the vertical and horizontal scrolls on a page. Are there events to handle the different directions, or just the `scroll` event?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
$('div.mySelector').on('scrollX', function(d){
    //Do stuff when scrolling left/right
})
```

But, of course, `scrollX` isn't an actual event. What's the best way to get this functionality?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930758/jquery-detecting-scroll-position, using jQuery. You probably have to store and compare the scroll position between the events, but that's easily done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind to the scroll.  Start by grabbing the scrollTop and scrollLeft of the element in question, and then compare them to the incoming values in your event handler to infer which type of scrolling might have occurred.  (It could be both, of course.)  If you're only interested in the X component of the scrolling, just act on it, store the new scrollLeft value, and then act again on the next call.