# How do I make my footer "stick" to bottom when "near" top of site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this working when the site is loaded. Footer at bottom. Then as you scroll to content it scrolls to top. Then when it reaches the top, it sticks (persistent Header) at top to be site navigation. This all works.

The problem is, when I scroll back to the top, I want the footer to once again "stick" to bottom. Right now it will end up above, or below the bottom of the browser depending on monitor.

I have read through the answers provided for similar topics, they address the footer sticking to the bottom, what I need is for it to "stick" back to the bottom once the user scrolls back near the top of the site.

Can someone help me accomplish this?

Here is the location of the test site and just scrolling will show my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/billy_comic/AQrsf/

```
     $(function(){
     var stickyRibbonTop = $('#main-nav').offset().top;

     $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
                    $('#main-nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else {
                    $('#main-nav').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            }
    });
    });
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

B

Comment: do the same thing you currently are doing except the opposite, check scroll if its at or lower than a certain point make the menu's `bottom:0px`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930758/jquery-detecting-scroll-position . Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you start from the assumption that the user's window height will not change, you can determine the minimum y position of the footer.

Then, when the user scrolls above this position you can change the header / footer's position from fixed (at `y = 0`) to absolute (at `y = window_height - header_footer_height`).

Expanding upon this, you can update the position also if the window height changes.

Comment: Would I do this in jquery or can this be accomplished using CSS3?

Comment: My instinct would be to use a combination: CSS for each state (`#whatever.header {...}`, `#whatever.footer {...}`), and use jQuery to toggle class at the appropriate time(s).

Comment: Ok, so should I just rewrite the above jquery for this, or adjust it? Sorry Dave, I'm a noob when it comes to jquery. Thanks