# How to catch scroll out event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, i catch scroll event like this

```
    $('.class').each(function () {
    $(this).appear(function() {
      $(this).action();

    }); 
});
```

Action toggle some class for element, works fine, but how to catch croll out from this section? Capture scroll on previous or next section - bad practice and false result for me.
Any ideas?

Comment: did any of my answer help you? are you still stuck? Perhaps you can provide us with a JS Fiddle if you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something to determine when an object leaves the visible screen?

If so, you may want to check out the [isInViewport jQuery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/isInViewport/).

You can also try attaching an event to the item's ["scroll" event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
$('.class').scroll(function(){
   // check position
});
```

(see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930758/jquery-detecting-scroll-position) for more details on how you can calculate scroll position)