# Applying CSS based on scroll(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I've written a script that increases the nav menu top-margin when my website is loaded as a web app on an iPad, however I'd like to add a third condition: after the user scrolls down.

My current script:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery("div").ready(function(){
        if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
        var array = window.navigator.userAgent.match("iPad"); if(array!=null && array.length == 1)
            jQuery(".menu-secondary-wrap").css("marginTop", "20px");
        };
    });
    </script>
```

I'd like to add:

```
    jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 175){
```

I'm just not sure how to do this - I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930758/jquery-detecting-scroll-position

Comment: I really need help with the structure/syntax for my specific requirement, not the function to use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this script before the closing `head` tag

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var scrollTopVal = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
    if(parseInt(scrollTopVal,10) > 175){
        //Your Stuff Here
    }
}
```

No need for jQuery. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2n8q9/4/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unsure how to merge it with my current conditions. I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/2n8q9/5/. I think I used jQuery so I could reference an ID instead of a class